# Print word after string

Tags: awk

How to print word after centrain string?

I have a file

```
Hello word.
```

I want to get an output:

```
#word
```

Something like

```
awk '{ print '#' }'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '{sub(/[[:punct:]]+$/, "", $2);print "#"$2}' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8SnTER).

The `sub(/[[:punct:]]+$/, "", $2)` operation removes 1 or more punctuation chars (`[[:punct:]]+`) from the end (`$`) of Field 2 and `print "#"$2` prepends it with `#` and prints it.

To make sure to get the word after `Hello` you may use

```
cat file | grep -Po 'Hello\s+\K\w+' | awk '{print "#"$0}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/urT7ku)

Or, with the help of `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*Hello \([[:alnum:]]*\).*/#\1/' file > newfile
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/Xo4ECn).

Here, `.*Hello \([[:alnum:]]*\).*` matches any 0+ chars, then `Hello`, a space, then captures 0 or more alphanumeric chars into Group 1 (`\1`) and then matches the rest of the line. The `#\1` pattern in the RHS leaves just what was captured with a `#` in front.

Another solution with `awk` with `.` and `/` as field delimiters using `-F'[/.]'`:

```
awk -F'[/.]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="54517334"){print "#"$(i+1)}}}' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/lYuqlY)

Here, `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` enumerates all the fields, and if the field is equal to `54517334`, the next field with a `#` prepended at the start is printed.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible a solution with the finding a string 'hello'. I gave only an example the file I need has more strings. It is not a file with columns.

Comment: @Elisabeth Could you please explain more?

Comment: For instance, I have in one column: something like: '/stackoverflow.com/questions/54517334/print-word-after-string' and I want to write #print-word-after-string , so I would like to write, that I want to print a string after '54517334/'

Comment: @Elisabeth, could you please check my EDIT solution too once?

Comment: @Elisabeth Edited with 2 more solutions.

Comment: Thank you and how to compile sed and cat in terminal?

Comment: @Elisabeth These tools must be there.

Comment: @Elisabeth If you want to work with `/`, use `awk -F'[/.]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="54517334"){print "#"$(i+1)}}}' file`

Comment: Thank you and what  does dot in  -F'[/.]' mean?

Comment: @Elisabeth `-F` is an option telling `awk` to use custom field delimiters. `[./]` is a regex, a bracket expression that matches any one char specified in the bracket expression, either `.` or `/`. You refer to fields using `$i` (`$1` is the first one, `$0` is the whole line).

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to search for a string and print string next to it then try following. I am looking for `hello` string here you could change it as per your need.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i)=="hello"){print "#"$(i+1)}}}' Input_file
```

OR(create an `awk` variable and perform checks, it will help in changing string in place of hello in variable itself)

```
awk -v word_to_search="hello" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i)==word_to_search){print "#"$(i+1)}}}'  Input_file
```

In case you want to print next keyword by finding a string and remove punctuations then try following.

```
awk -v word_to_search="hello" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i)==word_to_search){sub(/[[:punct:]]+/,"",$(i+1));print "#"$(i+1)}}}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ .]' '{print "#"$2}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F'[ .]' '{print $(NF-1)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Elisabeth, could you please try my EDIT solution and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Thank you and how to solve it for file 'Hello/word' ? Is / problem?

Comment: @Elisabeth, yes then set `-F'[/ ]'` after `awk` then it should work good. Let me know how it goes then?